# How does the Rust flag "link-self-contained" compare to cargo-cross?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, rust-cargo

How does `link-self-contained` work with [`cross`](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross), which is described as

> “Zero setup” cross compilation and “cross testing” of Rust crates

Versus the `link-self-contained` option of rustc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tools both have different goals so they aren't something that you would choose one over the other.

`link-self-contained` is choosing to build a self contained executable that will have everything it needs to run on any system that is the correct architecture. This includes any libraries that are used by the executable. The alternative (default) would be for the executable to look for libraries that are installed on the system when it is ran. Take a look into dynamic vs static libraries for more information on this.

`cross` is tooling to make it easier to cross compile and test for different architectures. Many times the runtime environment will have minimal resources and is not ideal to work on during the development process. Cross compiling is used so that development can be done on a machine with more resources. Setting up a cross compiler usually takes some time to do manually and so this tooling aims to make that process much simpler.

As far as how these work together, ideally they would perform the same way when both are being used. If you cross compile for an arm architecture and set the `link-self-contained` flag, then you will end up with a self contained binary that can be moved to any system using the correct arm architecture and have everything it needs to run.